# i want to post the form through codebehind and access the cookies and sessions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

i have two sites :

1. abc.com
2. xyz.com

the username/password for abc.com is : admin/admin

login page for abc.com is : abc.com/login.aspx

After correct login, the landing page is : abc.com/mypage.aspx

Now i need to use xyz.com for login

i need to enter the username/password in codebehind in xyz.com/delault.aspx

and it will check the login from abc.com/login.aspx and then redirect to abc.com/mypage.aspx

in xyz.com/default.aspx codebehind, the login process is automatic once the page has been load, and i can access the sessions that i get after the login.

Comment: to access one site form another site is very difficult. bythis u can create a site and check login of anywebsite like gmail , yahoo , facebook , etc...

But for that you have to create API or web-service for that abc.com so that u can send request  from xyz.com and if valid credential then it will be redirected abc.com/mypage.aspx